# NoClassFoundError MultipartEntity error in android

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartentity

I am not able to figure this problem out.I added the following jars.

```
httpClient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
httpmime-4.2.5.jar
```

I added these jar through `Add External JARs` option in `Build Paths` and then added them manually in the `libs` folder of my eclipse project still it gives me the following error while debugging the following line.

```
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

Actually I am trying to upload multiple images to my php server using this.

**Logcat:**

```
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SyncService]
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at com.example.cameralibrary.ServerCommunication.uploadUserPhoto(ServerCommunication.java:43)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at com.example.cameralibrary.SyncService.onHandleIntent(SyncService.java:38)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.cameralibrary-2.apk]
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-26 02:06:08.082: E/AndroidRuntime(20389):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out myself.The problem was that I didn't include the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
I added the following line in my manifest and it worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```